# Proper Bash Daemon Script Creation

Tags: linux, bash, init.d, start-stop-daemon

On Ubuntu, I copied `/etc/init.d/`skeleton as a new file and made it "all" executable (just like the others in that directory). In it, I made a "foo" that was just another Bash script in `/usr/sbin`, but it was special in that it sits in a loop waiting on a named pipe connection from a PHP web page. (More details on that are [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2841/4307), although that's a side topic.)

Because it has to wait in a loop on a named pipe connection, this hung the command up at command line obviously. Not a big deal, because I actually want it to hang and wait on a new connection. But I don't want it happening in the foreground. So, I made start-stop-daemon utilize the --background option.

Okay, it works great for starting and status, but stopping doesn't work -- it leaves the command in memory, as well as the `cat /tmp/pipe` command I have in my `/usr/sbin/foo` Bash script. They warn that this could happen when using the --background option on the start-stop-daemon command.

THE QUESTION

So, what's the right way to properly stop /usr/sbin/foo when it's run with `start-stop-daemon --background`, along with stop any child processes (the cat /tmp/pipe command, for instance) that might be called by /usr/sbin/foo? I mean, I guess I could use killall, but that's kind of deadly. Perhaps you know of a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in that situation the shell will be the leader of the [process group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group) containing the various commands run by the script. You can kill a process group by sending a signal to the opposite of the PID of the process group:

```
kill -TERM -$(cat /var/run/my_shell_daemon.pid)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend consulting the LSB:

http://refspecs.freestandards.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/tocsysinit.html

Here's a Debian-centric wiki on the same that may also be useful:

http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts

You typically stash a pid file somewhere under /var/run and then explicitly kill that command on stop.

Comment: Does the kill on a PID shut down all other commands? For instance, a 'cat /tmp/foo' command might still continue, called from within /usr/sbin/foo, right?

Comment: For more information on that, please read up on linux signal handling.  In general, yes, sending a KILL signal to the parent will work.